# POST Request not working in VBA (XML HTTP)

Tags: vba, post, xmlhttprequest

I am working on xmlHTTP request to extract JSON data from the web.

The below is my code.

```vb
    Public Sub testlibor2()
        Dim JSON As Object
        Dim ws As Worksheet, results(), i As Long, s As String
        Dim BL As String
        Dim mypara As String
        Dim mydest As String
        Dim URL, URL1, URL2, URL3 As String
    
        URL1 = "draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_ID&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=date&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=weekday&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%"
        URL2 = "5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=o&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_column&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=5&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_column_1&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=6&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=1m&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%"
        URL3 = "5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=7&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_column_2&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=8&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=3m&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=9&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_column_3&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=10&columns%"
        URL4 = "5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_column_4&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=11&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=6m&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=12&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_column_5&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bdata%5D=13&columns%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=wdt_column_6&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&column"
    
        mypara = URL1 & URL2 & URL3 & URL4
       
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "POST", "http://iborate.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=12", False
            .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
            .send mypara
            Debug.Print .responseText
            Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        End With
    
    End Sub
```

The code above does not work at all. I cannot receive any JSON data from this.

I have adjusted all the request Headers based on the details from the Chrome dev Tools, and I have
absolutely no Idea what the issue is.

The original URL is as below. I am trying to access the table in the web.

http://iborate.com/usd-libor/

Thank you!

One additional question. Are there any alternatives to dealing with URL strings that are too long to be contained inside one variable? I divided the string as below but I am not sure if this is the best way to handle it.

**UPDATE**

Based on @QHarr's idea I have changed the Form data into a JSON string. However the code still does not work.

```
Public Sub testlibor2()
Dim JSON As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet, results(), i As Long, s As String
Dim shipvalue As String, custom As String, MyURL As String
Dim BL As String
Dim mypara, newpara As String

Dim URL, URL1, URL2, URL3, URL4, URL5 As String

 
URL1 = "{""draw"":""2"",""columns[0][data]"":""0"",""columns[0][name]"":""wdt_ID"",""columns[0][searchable]"":""true"",""columns[0][orderable]"":""true"",""columns[0][search][value]"":"""",""columns[0][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[1][data]"": ""1"",""columns[1][name]"": ""date"",""columns[1][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[1][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[1][search][value]"": ""|"",""columns[1][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[2][data]"": ""2"",""columns[2][name]"": ""weekday"",""columns[2][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[2][orderable]"":""true"",""columns[2][search][value]"": """","
URL2 = """columns[2][search][regex]"":""false"",""columns[3][data]"":""3"",""columns[3][name]"": ""o"",""columns[3][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[3][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[3][search][value]"": """",""columns[3][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[4][data]"": ""4"",""columns[4][name]"": ""wdt_column"",""columns[4][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[4][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[4][search][value]"": """",""columns[4][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[5][data]"": ""5"",""columns[5][name]"": ""wdt_column_1"",""columns[5][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[5][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[5][search][value]"": """",""columns[5][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[6][data]"": ""6"",""columns[6][name]"": ""1m"",""columns[6][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[6][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[6][search][value]"": """",""columns[6][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[7][data]"": ""7"",""columns[7][name]"": ""wdt_column_2"",""columns[7][searchable]"": ""true"","
URL3 = """columns[7][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[7][search][value]"": """",""columns[7][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[8][data]"": ""8"",""columns[8][name]"": ""3m"",""columns[8][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[8][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[8][search][value]"": """",""columns[8][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[9][data]"": ""9"",""columns[9][name]"": ""wdt_column_3"",""columns[9][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[9][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[9][search][value]"": """",""columns[9][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[10][data]"": ""10"",""columns[10][name]"": ""wdt_column_4"",""columns[10][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[10][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[10][search][value]"": """",""columns[10][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[11][data]"": ""11"",""columns[11][name]"": ""6m"",""columns[11][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[11][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[11][search][value]"": """",""columns[11][search][regex]"": ""false"","
URL4 = """columns[12][data]"": ""12"",""columns[12][name]"": ""wdt_column_5"",""columns[12][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[12][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[12][search][value]"": """",""columns[12][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[13][data]"": ""13"",""columns[13][name]"": ""wdt_column_6"",""columns[13][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[13][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[13][search][value]"": """",""columns[13][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[14][data]"": ""14"",""columns[14][name]"": ""wdt_column_7"",""columns[14][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[14][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[14][search][value]"": """",""columns[14][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[15][data]"": ""15"",""columns[15][name]"": ""wdt_column_8"",""columns[15][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[15][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[15][search][value]"": """",""columns[15][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[16][data]"": ""16"",""columns[16][name]"": ""wdt_column_9"",""columns[16][searchable]"": ""true"","
URL5 = """columns[16][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[16][search][value]"": """",""columns[16][search][regex]"": ""false"",""columns[17][data]"": ""17"",""columns[17][name]"": ""12m"",""columns[17][searchable]"": ""true"",""columns[17][orderable]"": ""true"",""columns[17][search][value]"": """",""columns[17][search][regex]"": ""false"",""order[0][column]"": ""1"",""order[0][dir]"": ""desc"",""start"": ""0"",""length"": ""10"",""search[value]"": """",""search[regex]"": ""false"",""wdtNonce"": ""ce62a523fa"",""sRangeSeparator"": ""|""}"

mypara = URL1 & URL2 & URL3 & URL4 & URL5
newpara = Replace(mypara, " ", "")
Debug.Print newpara


    
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "POST", "http://iborate.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=12", False
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"      
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"

    .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
    .send newpara
    Debug.Print .responseText
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With
End Sub
```

I have checked couple of times to make sure the JSON string is exactly identical as the one suggested below from QHarr.

Can anyone identify a solution from here?

Comment: Hanalia wrote: "The code above does not work at all"
1. Any error messages? 
2. Did you set breakpoints and single stepped through the code?

Comment: Yes I did. I have set the breakpoints(The above is actually only the first part of the entire code.)  The main issue is that Debug.Print.responseText results in blank.

Comment: Then you need to follow these guidelines:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [Urldecode](https://pastebin.com/8jzxs0U2) the data and try sending again

Comment: It may be that the server expects json

Comment: seems you have some familiarity with python. Use requests and the default python headers. https://pastebin.com/ewh9mqpV

Comment: @QHarr Thank you I think your idea is the right way to solve the problem. But right now I am trying to make this program to be easily accessible to non-python users. Is there any way I can send the URL decoded data through VBA XML HTTP request?

Comment: I think, though not 100%, is that the server is expecting a json string (urldecoded). I would look at past answers that deal specifically with that to see if any clues.

Comment: QHarr Thank you for your help. But unfortunately, this still does not work. I may have no choice but to work on it with Python... But thank you very much.